# VB .NET - How to set a vbTab with a point?

Tags: vb.net

Background: 
Create a log file with text(Done), but did not set vbTab successful

---

Format:
[DateTime][UserName][ClassName] [vbTab] [LogIndexMessage]

---

Example:

```
[01 Jan,2016 24:59:59 PM][LocalHost\User][Class1]              This is Message1
[01 Jan,2016 24:59:59 PM][LocalHost\User][Class2NameWasLongerThanClass1Name]              This is Message2
```

---

If I want to set a fixed point with tab location to make it like:

```
[01 Jan,2016 24:59:59 PM][LocalHost\User][Class1]                             This is Message1
[01 Jan,2016 24:59:59 PM][LocalHost\User][Class2NameWasLongerThanClass1Name]  This is Message2
```

---

How could I set a tab to some location that was fixed like as I said before?
Most of the people told me that there has an other way to set the space side like this:

```
Log_String = String.Format("{0,-7}{1,-2}{2,-2}{3,-50}", _Date & _User & _Class & _Message)
```

But for some of the char size was not same, so that I was to know any way to set Tab to a location?

Best Regards,
Koi Tsang

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    Dim strTag = vbTab
    Dim iLen = 100
    Dim strTime1 = "[01 Jan,2016 24:59:59 PM][LocalHost\User][Class1]"
    Dim strMg1 = "This is Message1"
    Dim strTime2 = "[01 Jan,2016 24:59:59 PM][LocalHost\User][Class2NameWasLongerThanClass1Name]"
    Dim strMg2 = "This is Message2"
    Dim iChar1 = strTime1.Length + strMg1.Length
    Dim strRow1 = strTime1 & strTag.PadLeft(iLen - iChar1) + strMg1

    Dim iChar2 = strTime2.Length + strMg2.Length
    Dim strRow2 = strTime2 & strTag.PadLeft(iLen - iChar2) + strMg2
```